# How to prove that $(a + (b^2 + k^2)^{1/2}) > (c + (d^2 + k^2)^{1/2})$, given that $(a + b) > (c + d)$?

Tags: calculus

What is the simplest/best way to show that:

If $(a + b) > (c + d)$ then $(a + (b^2 + k^2)^{1/2}) > (c + (d^2 + k^2)^{1/2})$?

For context, I have a VR environment and I want to find the shortest path between O and T. There are Walls and computing possible paths is not easy so I hard-coded corridors and intersections using a weighted graph (red vertices).

Targets positions are variable and, once again, its not easy to see if there is a path between them and the remaining nodes so, T and arcs i,j are not part of the graph.

The problem I stated is the following: It is correct to assume that the nodes of the graph belonging to the shortest path between O and T (if T was connect to the graph) are the sames as the ones between O and the nearest graph node?

In other words, If the shortest path between O and N if by "2", then the shortest path between O and T, if i and j arcs existed, would also be by "2"?

a = a' + a'' so: if a+b > c+d then a + i > c + j?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 4):

Not true.  Note that $1 + 4 = 2 + 3$ but $1 + \sqrt{4^2 + 3^2} = 6 < 2 + \sqrt{3^2 + 3^2} = 2 + 3 \sqrt{2}$.  So for $a$ slightly greater than $1$, 
$a + 4 > 2 + 3$ while still $a + \sqrt{4^2 + 3^2} < 2 + \sqrt{3^2 + 3^2}$.

Comment: nice, quick counterexample! +1

Comment: yes, thanks :) I was focusing, without reason, what examples with a>>b... i don't know if that explains my difficulties.. but, since that condition is not necessary in my problem... your solution is great.. btw, is there any method to solve this kind of problems algebrically? like my manipulating inequalities? thanks